# My InternalResourceViewResolver not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-jdbc

I am trying develope a small application using Spring Framework with Annotation but i really not able to recognized what i made mistake that `InternalResourceViewResolver` class not handling request that is coming from `.jsp` page. here is my project details.

> index.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="login.form" ></jsp:forward>
```

> spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nody.spring.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <!-- Handler Mapping -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMappping"></bean>

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"   value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix"   value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jt"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource"  ref="ds"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ds"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
    <property name="url"  value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
    <property name="username"  value="scott"></property>
    <property name="password"  value="tiger"></property>
    </bean>
   </beans>
```

> LoginController.java

```
package com.nody.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

        private LoginService loginService;

        @Autowired
        public void setLoginService(LoginService loginService) {
            this.loginService = loginService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/login.form", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getLoginPage()
        {
            return new ModelAndView("login");
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="check", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView checkLogin(@RequestParam("uname")String s1,@RequestParam("pword")String s2)
        {
            boolean b=loginService.check(s1,s2);
            if(b)
                return new ModelAndView("success");
            else
                return new ModelAndView("failure");
        }

    }
```

> LoginService.java

```
package com.nody.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class LoginService {

    private JdbcTemplate jt;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jt")
    public void setJt(JdbcTemplate jt)
    {
        this.jt=jt;
    }
    public boolean check(String s1,String s2)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int i=jt.queryForInt("select count(*) from users where uname=? and pword=?",s1,s2);
        if(i==1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }


}
```

> List of jars

```
aspectj-weaver.jar
atomikos-transactions-api.jar
atomikos-transactions-jta.jar
atomikos-util.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar
javax.transaction-3.1.jar
jta.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
ojdbc14.jar
spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
transactions-3.7.0.jar
transactions-jdbc-3.7.0.jar
aopalliance.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar
```

> failure.jsp

```
<form action="check.form" method="POST">
Username:<input type=text name="uname"><br>
Password<input type=password name="pword"><br>
<input type=submit value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

> success.jsp

```
<h1>Login Success !!!</h1>
```

> failure.jsp

```
<h1>Login Success !!!</h1>
```

> and Oracle Table name is 'users' with 2 columns 'uname' and 'pword'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, if I understand correctly, but you have an error with loading .jsp pages?

```
<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix"   value="/"></property>
<property name="suffix"   value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

Looks like you saying to spring, to look for .jsp pages in direct directory (webapp probably). Where do you keep your .jsp files? You should provide exact folder which containts .jsp files, like `<beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />`

Comment: I am using Eclipse and i placed all .jsp file in "WebContent" folder

Comment: IDE doesn't matter. You need to make sure, that you have correct path .jsp files as a **value** at **prefix bean**.

Comment: i verified it takes .jsp file but not proceeding it for further